# Embedded Glassfish - EJB 3.1 - @Schedule

Tags: java-ee-6, glassfish-3, cdi, ejb-3.1, glassfish-embedded

I am new to Java EE 6 and working on getting a number of demo applications running finally.

I have an application scoped bean that has a @Schedule annotation on it that should in theory trigger that method every minute.  However, that method doesn't appear to ever be invoked.  It simply writes to the logs that it was called.

Can I use EJB3.1 on embedded glassfish?  Do I need to do anything special to make it work?

Walter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (...) However, that method doesn't appear to ever be invoked. It simply writes to the logs that it was called.

Hmm... What?

> Can I use EJB3.1 on embedded glassfish? Do I need to do anything special to make it work?

Embedded GlassFish is like a full GlassFish, there are no restrictions. So you can use EJB 3.1 with the full Java EE profile imeplementation and you can use EJB 3.1 Lite with the Web Profile implementation. I'm not sure `@Schedule` is part of EJB 3.1 Lite tough.

Comment: You're right, I was able to use @Schedule, I noticed that glassfish looked for an ejb timer and didn't find one.  My wording was a little confusing.  What I was trying to say was that the method that should be invoked by the scheduler simply writes to the logs.